# How to create a batch file that checks for EXE version then does an action?

Tags: batch-file, version

I checked around but didn't get this specific detail. I want to create a batch file that Checks if the version is equal to the version i specify and performs an action accordingly, in this case it would exit. The point from this code is that it would check if the newer version is created and would exit if it is fulfilled.

Comment: How are you hoping to determine the version of the .exe - from its file name, its file properties, or by running it with a special parameter like -v that will make it report its version? (Or some other way I haven't thought of?)

Answer (score -3):

Program EXE files contain version information in a resource inserted in the file. The information is visible in the Windows Explorer when you view the properties of program files, but unfortunately Windows has no command line utility to access it. But it is not dificult to write such utility, because the API GetFileVersionInfo is fully documented. Some third party tools, some of them open source, exist. A little quick Google on the subject has lead me to some links.